# How to dynamically create a document in the GAE Search API?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to understand how i can dynamically add fields in my document.

I am following [the doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/#Java_Creating_a_document) . However i'd like to use the addField method inside a "for" statement and thus programmatically generate fields.

I've tried this :

```js
Builder document = Document.newBuilder();
document.setId(id);

// for statement start
com.google.appengine.api.search.Field.Builder field = Field.newBuilder().setName(key).setAtom(value);
document.addField(field);
// for statement end

document.build();
```

But it doesn't seems to work. When i'm trying i got this printed out

```
com.google.appengine.api.search.Document$Builder@2604ed54
```

Whereas when i use the original code :

```js
String myDocId = "PA6-5000";
Document doc = Document.newBuilder()
    // Setting the document identifer is optional.
    // If omitted, the search service will create an identifier.
    .setId(myDocId)
    .addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("content").setText("the rain in spain"))
    .addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("email").setText(userEmail))
    .addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("domain").setAtom(userDomain))
    .addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("published").setDate(new Date()))
    .build();
```

I get the expected result with the code above.

How i can manipulate this in order to put addfield() into for statement ?

thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs imply the Document.Builder is mutable, but typically you should reassign the builder after each invocation in case it isn't.

```
Builder document = Document.newBuilder();
document.setId(id);
com.google.appengine.api.search.Field.Builder field = Field.newBuilder().setName(key).setAtom(value);
document = document.addField(field);
document.build();
```

In your case what you're seeing is the toString() method on the builder, not the document itself. The problem is the last line.

Try this:

```
Builder builder = Document.newBuilder();
builder.setId(id);
com.google.appengine.api.search.Field.Builder field = Field.newBuilder().setName(key).setAtom(value);
builder = builder.addField(field);
Document document = builder.build();
```

Then you can just drop in your for loop and away you go.

Comment: Thank you. That works fine. It was pretty tricky to understand even by reading the doc. But now, it's okay i could successfully create my documents dynamically by following your tip. You solved my issue. Thanks.